# Null pointer exception in selenium framework

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, testng

Hi I have three classes

1. Drivermethod:
   In this class I created a method "initiate" to initialise driver

   ```
   public class Drivermethod {
       public WebDriver driver;

       public static WebDriver initiate(WebDriver driver){
           System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Automation\\IEDriverSeer_Win32_3.8.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
           driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
           return driver;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Levelmanage:
   In this class I created a method "managelink" to find an element.

   ```
   public class Levelmanage {
       public static  WebElement element;

       public static WebElement managelink(WebDriver driver) {
           element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manager link"));
           return element;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Test1

   ```
   public class Test1  {

   public WebDriver driver;

   @Test
   public void f() {
       Drivermethod.initiate(driver).get("url");
       Levelmanage.managelink(driver).click();
   }
   ```

In third class am calling the first 2 method...When I run this class(Test1),The first method execution is happening when it goes to the second one(Levelmanage.managelink(driver).click();) driver is getting NULL. Kindly help me on this....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not initializing your `driver` field from the test class.

```
public class Test1 {

public WebDriver driver;

     @Test public void f() {
          driver = Drivermethod.initiate(driver).get("url");
          Levelmanage.managelink(driver).click();
     }
}
```

Also, for the initiate method, the `WebDriver parameter` is useless. That's the place where you're creating your driver, you're not receiving it from anywhere.

Besides this, in case you don't have any other methods in your `Drivermethod` class, the `field WebDriver` is useless as well. And I'm guessing this is the case, since it's not assigned anywhere.